# Overload for LINQ List.Contains() to accept column name

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I would like to modify the following procedure

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetMany(List<int> values)
        {
             List<TEntity> entities = await _crudApiDbContext.Set<TEntity>()
                    .Where(entity => values.Contains(entity.Id)).ToListAsync();
             return new OkObjectResult(entities);
        }
```

to accept the column name which will be searched in the Contains method, something like:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetMany(List<int> values, string colName)
        {
             List<TEntity> entities = await _crudApiDbContext.Set<TEntity>()
                    .Where(entity => values.Contains<TEntity>(colName)).ToListAsync();
             return new OkObjectResult(entities);
        }
```

I've tried overloading Contains and using expression trees but got lost...

Any ideas?

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce the following extension method, which should filter any entity type by collection:

```cs
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> FilterByList<TEntity, TKey>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query, IEnumerable<TKey> values, string colName) 
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "e");
        var propAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, colName);
        var listExpr = Expression.Constant(values);

        var predicate = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Contains", new[] {typeof(TKey)}, listExpr,
            propAccess);

        var predicateLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(predicate, param);

        return query.Where(predicateLambda);
    }
}
```

And rewrite your `GetMany` to this variant:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> GetMany<TEntity>(List<int> values, string colName)
{
    var entities = await _crudApiDbContext.Set<TEntity>()
        .FilterByList(values, colName)
        .ToListAsync();
    return new OkObjectResult(entities);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly and so elegant!  Maybe this is the time I do learn about reflection... Thanks!